# NavigatorController Button not displaying popup alert

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, selector

I was creating a simple Navigationcontroller Button to show an alert to click but it fails to do Please find the code below:

```
//Enable the buttons to edit
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Edit", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(EditEnable(sender:)))


@objc private func EditEnable(sender: UIBarButtonItem)
{
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Time to change the Menu for Next Week",
                                  message: "Message",
                                  preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default))
}
```

Not sure what I am doing is wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're forgetting to show the alert.

```
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```